# How to implement custom camera functionality in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to develop a functionality such that to implement custom camera functionality in iPhone apps so please give me any link or any idea to develop this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is as unclear as it could get.

Comment: to develop custom camera functionality in iphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by custom camera? You can only use the ***UIImagePickerController*** which brings up a defautlt camera interface  to capture images or videos. You can use ***camera overlay*** to show some custom view as overlay.

You can use some ***image processing techniques*** if you want to do any image alteration or something on the captured images.